# (Fullcalendar 4 VueJs) Swap header titleFormat Month and Day

Tags: javascript, date, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I need to swap header title, by default "Month" goes first and "Day" goes second. I need the other way around.

I use this prop:

```
 :titleFormat="{ day: '2-digit', month: 'long' }"
```

But "Month" goes first anyway. I found a solution here: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3443 but how to adjust this for VueJS way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3443 will not be relevant to you because that's discussing the formatting options for fullCalendar v3. In v4 it's different again.

Comment: Unfortunately in v4 there doesn't seem to be a facility to create a completely custom title (like there is for column headers, for example). Perhaps it should be a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features)

Comment: P.S. As a last resort I guess you could simply use JavaScript to amend the contents of the div which contains the title directly, rather than using the API. But you need to ensure you update it yourself every time the date range changes - for that you can probably handle the datesRender event in fullCalendar.

Comment: I see. Yes, i was thinking about using JS directly with title to swap it, the title is just one tag     "<h2>July 08 - 14</h2>" so i need to parse the string to swap it. I thought there can be a better way.
    Thank you, ADyson!

Answer (score 1):

My personal solution that helped me is:

```
   datesRender(){
    let elTitle = this.$refs.fullCalendar.$el.querySelector('.fc-center h2');
    let elTitleText = elTitle.innerHTML;
    elTitle.innerHTML = elTitleText.replace(/^([a-z]+) (\d{2,2}\s?-\s?\d{2,2})$/i, '$2 $1');
  },
```

This swapped string "July 08 - 14" to "08 - 14 July".